# How are light years measured?

Tags: cosmology

I know what a light year is but do not know how they are measured.I have tried several sites and can not find the answer. I thought you might have it.

Comment: With a ruler, for instance, just convert metres or inches to fractions of light years. (I'm obviously not understanding what you're asking, can you try to make it more precise?)

Comment: The light year is a definition based on the speed of light in a vacuum, and therefore is not a measured quantity, but a defined one.  Are you trying to ask how the distance to galaxies and stars are measured?

Comment: A light year is a distance equal to a speed (speed of light in a vacuum) multiplied by a time (one calendar year). It's straightforward to measure the length of a year; check [Speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Measurement) if you are interested in learning about how the speed of light is measured.

Comment: Is the question "how do we know something is a certain number of light years away?" which is a very large distance. For closer stars, parallax methods are used when the earth is goes through half an orbit around the sun and the angular displacement of the close by star with respect to the background stars allow the calculation. the there is the main sequence star calculations that allow us to calculate distance by brightness and the "color" of the star.And it goes from there. A good book on astronomy will explain all of this.

Comment: @PeterR You can even go closer. The distance between the earth and the moon is approx 1.4 light seconds. And between the earth and the sun it's 8,33 light minutes.

Comment: He is asking light years not light seconds or light minutes.

Answer (score 2):

> How are light years measured?

They aren't actually measured. It's like what tmwilson said, they're defined. Imagine you can look up at the sky and watch a big green laser beam going across it:

[image]

You sit there watching it for exactly a year and then you jump up with your hands outstretched and you say "*that's* a light year".

> I know what a light year is but do not know how they are measured.I have tried several sites and can not find the answer. I thought you might have it.

Maybe you could ask how distances are measured and/or estimated in astronomy / astrophysics / cosmology?